# Some words(be trained) can not be recognised through Tesseract-OCR

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract, image-recognition, training-data

I am currently using Tesseract-OCR to recognize some texts in a picture .But now I have a question.Since some words can not be recognized .I specially have trained them and it still did not work!

Should I need some extra files when train the language data like the DAWG files or etc. I 
have no idea about that. Because sometimes it can recognize a few of them when the words display at some special positions and directions .

It is really confusing . Sincerely need your help. Thanks in advance!

Other info:

1. I am using the Simplified Chinese.(I don't know if there are any parameters that I did not set when using Chinese)
2. Since the picture I wanna recognize is a table. there are a few lines in it. Could you have any idea on this situation when recognizing tables to improve the accuracy.
3. Since I don't know if it is caused by the special shape of the words. I paste some words directly here.  上下午一二三四五

Many thanks !

Comment: I've never use the Simplified Chinese version, but sometimes tesseract can work better if you resize the image bigger (and some people have reported improvements resizing to a smaller image).  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951598/tesseract-has-trouble-reading-this-extremely-simple-string-of-numbers/      I am not sure about question #2 could you please explain more.  You mean a table with values in the cells?

Comment: Yeah,Thank you very much! I've Thought that no one would answer my question.

Comment: Uh. well, I think it's not the problem of 'dpi' since I've already tested that through other softwares. Yeah, maybe, you know, there are many points(by changing to use another algorithms or etc.) to improve the accuracy when recognize some specified language like chi_sim.  But here I wanna know some solutions(just by setting the parameters in Tesseract to improve the accuracy and even the speed) to do that. One phenomenon is that it always combine two vertical words(have spaces among them) to one.

Comment: Tesseract even for English does not work too well.  So I am not surprised that it is having problems with chi_sim.  Perhaps you can take a few words, make the font simple and big and see if Tesseract can recognize the words.  If it cannot, then maybe you will need to do some preprocessing.

Comment: I am dealing with some sheets(u know, like 'MS excel', there are some grids and even some diagonals among with the words). Sorry for my poor English. The question #2 describes this case. I wonder if the lines could affect the accuracy of recognizing words.  Also what I am doing now is to extract the sheets and draw that in GUI. I've completed that through an another 3rd Library.Since it calculates one more time, I wanna know if this already exist in source code.(Or just code a little by the source code, Because when I check it out and find some functions like 'findLines' and 'tablefind',etc.)

Comment: Finding lines would be a great help to your OCR program.  However finding lines can be difficult.  If you can find something like the hough transform that will find lines and allow you to isolate each cell and feed that to the OCR engine.    I still think you should do a test where you manually split the table (copy and paste the image) this will be the ideal case.  Feed the manually split regions to the OCR engine and observe the accuracy.  If it is good then "all" you need to do is split the table automatically.  If the OCR results are still not good then you will need to improve the OCR